# in_app_purchase purchaseUpdatedStream listen event not firing

Tags: flutter

I want to subscribe to the `purchaseUpdatedStream` event after my app has initialised as I want to access localization text to display messages to the user if a purchase has failed. However I can't get the listen event to fire unless it's subscribed BEFORE the `MaterialApp` widget is built.

Working example:

```dart
class AppConfig extends InheritedWidget {
  AppConfig({
    @required this.appName,
    @required Widget child,
    @required this.prefs,
    @required this.devMode
  }) : super(child: child);

  final String appName;
  final SharedPreferences prefs;
  final bool devMode;

  static AppConfig of(BuildContext context) {
    return context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType();
  }

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(InheritedWidget oldWidget) => false;
}

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  var configuredApp = new AppConfig(
    appName: 'app',
    child: new MyApp(),
    prefs: await SharedPreferences.getInstance(),
    devMode: true,
  );

  InAppPurchaseConnection.enablePendingPurchases();
  runApp(configuredApp);
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  StreamSubscription<List<PurchaseDetails>> _subscription;

  @override
  void initState() {
    Stream purchaseUpdated =
        InAppPurchaseConnection.instance.purchaseUpdatedStream;
    _subscription = purchaseUpdated.listen((purchaseDetailsList) {
      _listenToPurchaseUpdated(purchaseDetailsList, context);
    }, onDone: () {
      _subscription.cancel();
    }, onError: (error) {
      // handle error here.
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _subscription.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _listenToPurchaseUpdated(List<PurchaseDetails> purchaseDetailsList, BuildContext context) {
    var config = AppConfig.of(context);
    purchaseDetailsList.forEach((PurchaseDetails purchaseDetails) async {
      if (purchaseDetails.status == PurchaseStatus.pending) {
        print('pending');
      } else {
        if (purchaseDetails.status == PurchaseStatus.error) {
          print('error');
        } else if (purchaseDetails.status == PurchaseStatus.purchased) {
          print('purchased');
        }
        if (purchaseDetails.pendingCompletePurchase) {
          print('complete');
          await InAppPurchaseConnection.instance
              .completePurchase(purchaseDetails);
        }
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var config = AppConfig.of(context);

    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
    ]);

    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: config.appName,
        home: Scaffold(
          body: SomeWidget(); // whack a button in this widget that triggers a product purchase
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Non-working example:

```dart
class AppConfig extends InheritedWidget {
  AppConfig({
    @required this.appName,
    @required Widget child,
    @required this.prefs,
    @required this.devMode
  }) : super(child: child);

  final String appName;
  final SharedPreferences prefs;
  final bool devMode;

  static AppConfig of(BuildContext context) {
    return context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType();
  }

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(InheritedWidget oldWidget) => false;
}

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  var configuredApp = new AppConfig(
    appName: 'app',
    child: new AppScaffold(),
    prefs: await SharedPreferences.getInstance(),
    devMode: true,
  );

  InAppPurchaseConnection.enablePendingPurchases();
  runApp(configuredApp);
}

class AppScaffold extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var config = AppConfig.of(context);

    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
    ]);

    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: config.appName,
        home: Scaffold(
          body: MyApp()
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  StreamSubscription<List<PurchaseDetails>> _subscription;

  @override
  void initState() {
    Stream purchaseUpdated =
        InAppPurchaseConnection.instance.purchaseUpdatedStream;
    _subscription = purchaseUpdated.listen((purchaseDetailsList) {
      _listenToPurchaseUpdated(purchaseDetailsList, context);
    }, onDone: () {
      _subscription.cancel();
    }, onError: (error) {
      // handle error here.
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _subscription.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _listenToPurchaseUpdated(List<PurchaseDetails> purchaseDetailsList, BuildContext context) {
    var config = AppConfig.of(context);
    purchaseDetailsList.forEach((PurchaseDetails purchaseDetails) async {
      if (purchaseDetails.status == PurchaseStatus.pending) {
        print('pending');
      } else {
        if (purchaseDetails.status == PurchaseStatus.error) {
          print('error');
        } else if (purchaseDetails.status == PurchaseStatus.purchased) {
          print('purchased');
        }
        if (purchaseDetails.pendingCompletePurchase) {
          print('complete');
          await InAppPurchaseConnection.instance
              .completePurchase(purchaseDetails);
        }
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SomeWidget(); // whack a button in this widget that triggers a product purchase
  }
}
```

Can anyone see if I'm going about this the wrong way and/or explain why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My own fault - I was using `Navigator.pushReplacement(...);` elsewhere in the app which was triggering the dispose method on the child widget. Obvious now I think about it.